# Extending forms in django?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I recently tried extending django's registration form with the following but i can only see the default four fields. IS there anything i'm missing?

Or should i be creating my own registration backend if i were to create a custom form?

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):

    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',
                                max_length=30,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),
                                label=_(u'Username'))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,
                                                               maxlength=75)),
                             label=_(u'Email address'))
    first_name =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_(u'First Name')) 
    last_name =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_(u'Last Name'))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
                                label=_(u'Password'))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False),
                                label=_(u'Password (again)'))
    keywords = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Keyword.objects.all())
    #keywords = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Keyword.objects.all())

    def clean_username(self):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.cleaned_data['username'])
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return self.cleaned_data['username']
        raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'This username is already taken. Please choose another.'))

    def clean(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'You must type the same password each time'))
        return self.cleaned_data

    def save(self, profile_callback=None):
        new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],email=self.cleaned_data['email'],profile_callback=profile_callback)
    new_profile = UserProfile(user=new_user,username=self.cleaned_data['username'], keywords_subscribed=self.cleaned_data['keywords'],first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'],email=self.cleaned_data['email'])
    new_profile.save()       
        return new_user
```

**Added the template code:**

The template code is added for reference.

It's referencing from the forms.py in the registration module

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="popupLayer_login" style="visibility: visible; position: fixed;">
            <div id="content-home" style="width: 700px; margin-left: -300px; top: 60px; position: fixed;">
                <br />
                {% block title %}<h2 style="margin: 0px; margin-bottom: 20px; text-align: center">Register for an account</h2>{% endblock %}
                {% block content %}
                <table style="margin-left: 100px; width: 500px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <form method='post' action=''>
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form }}
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-width: 0px;"></td>
                                <td style="border-width: 0px;">
                                <input type="submit" value="Send activation email" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is my urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       # Activation keys get matched by \w+ instead of the more specific
                       # [a-fA-F0-9]{40} because a bad activation key should still get to the view;
                       # that way it can return a sensible "invalid key" message instead of a
                       # confusing 404.
                       url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
                           activate,
                           name='registration_activate'),
                       url(r'^login/$',
                           auth_views.login,
                           {'template_name': 'registration/login.html'},
                           name='auth_login'),
                       url(r'^logout/$',
                           auth_views.logout,
                           {'template_name': 'registration/logout.html'},
                           name='auth_logout'),
                       url(r'^password/change/$',
                           auth_views.password_change,
                           name='auth_password_change'),
                       url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_change_done,
                           name='auth_password_change_done'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset,
                           name='auth_password_reset'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                           name='auth_password_reset_confirm'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                           name='auth_password_reset_complete'),
                       url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                           auth_views.password_reset_done,
                           name='auth_password_reset_done'),
                       url(r'^register/$',
                           register,
                           name='registration_register'),
                       url(r'^register/complete/$',
                           direct_to_template,
                           {'template': 'registration/registration_complete.html'},
                           name='registration_complete'),
                       )
```

**and my views.py**

```
def register(request, success_url=None,
             form_class=RegistrationForm, profile_callback=None,
             template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
             extra_context=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(profile_callback=profile_callback)
            # success_url needs to be dynamically generated here; setting a
            # a default value using reverse() will cause circular-import
            # problems with the default URLConf for this application, which
            # imports this file.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(success_url or reverse('registration_complete'))
    else:
        form = form_class()

    if extra_context is None:
        extra_context = {}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value
    return render_to_response(template_name,
                              { 'form': form },
                              context_instance=context)
```

Comment: Can we see the template code ?

Comment: Why your form does not derive from django registration form?

Comment: @jpic added the template code in already.

Comment: Thanks, and your view, and urls actually, that will let you have a more specific answer

Comment: @jpic done. I only added the registration method cos that's the place where it's failing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, **you are not supposed to modify the code of an external app**, unless you have a really good reason to - which apparently this case doesn't. Because that's called a fork and requires more maintenance: they do an update, you'd have to reflect the updates.

You should **always try to reuse the external app without touching its code**. In this case, it is perfectly possible to extend the registration form without touching their code. That said, it requires a little voodoo. Note that this works for any sane app:

1. **Check for a form_class argument in the view signature**, the view in question has such a signature: `request(request, success_url=None, form_class=RegistrationForm, profile_callback=None, template_name='registration/registration_form.html', extra_context=None)`. That's pretty cool, it means that you can reuse the view with different success urls, profile callbacks, templates, extra context and most importantly in your case: form_class.
2. **Subclass the form**, create another form which inherits from RegistrationForm
3. **Override the URL to pass your form class**, create another url which passes your form class

Create a forms.py in your project directory:

```
from django import forms

from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class ProjectSpecificRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    keywords = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Keyword.objects.all())
    first_name =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_(u'First Name')) 
    last_name =forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_(u'Last Name'))
```

Then, in **your** urls.py, you should have something like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'registration/', include('registration.urls'),
)
```

Override the url named "registration_register" with absolute path `/registration/register/` url as such:

```
import forms

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^registration/register/$', 'views.registration.register', {
        'form_class': forms.ProjectSpecificRegistrationForm}, 'registration_register'),
    url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls'),
)
```

**What's going on here**

The [url() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#url) has such a signature: `url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')`. In the above definition, we are passing a dict with form_class to kwargs. So the view will be called with form_class=your form class. It's quite interesting really because you could also add extra context like:

```
    url(r'^registration/register/$', 'views.registration.register', {
        'form_class': forms.ProjectSpecificRegistrationForm,
        # provided that you imported SomeModel
        'extra_context':  {'models': SomeModel.objects.all()}}, 'registration_register'),
```

**Anyway next time you open `/registration/register/`, it will use your url, which passes your form class.**

Note that you could also create a an app like *project_specific* where you'd put all the code that is really specific to your project and has no reason to be reused.

Comment: wow that's a really good explanation. OK let me try it out and come back and accept. But it definitely does get my vote. Thanks! :D

Comment: question though, the forms.py can be anywhere in the project directory? and for the urls.py, do i modify the registration urls.py or the main urls.py?

Comment: I repeat, do **not** modify the code in the external app ! find **your project urls.py** which should **include** the external app's urls, and add your url override **above** that url include. forms.py can be anywhere really **as long as you can import it in your main urls.py**.

Comment: how do i define this? name 'attrs_dict' is not defined

Comment: You could import it: from registration.forms import RegistrationForm, attrs_dict

Comment: ok thank you so much. I will never try to modify an external app again. :D cheers