# Django extend own custom form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am currently having trouble with some logic. First off, I come from PHP and I am fairly new to Django.

At the moment I am working on a purchase order process. Standard process:
Customer selects product, enters details, reviews order, goes off to paypal etc.

There are two types of users: a customer and a registered user. 
Customers can be companies or private people. That however, does not matter.

There can be a normal user (registered user) that is just there for the newsletter and a customer, someone who actually pays and owns the product.

Therefore, I have a normal user registration on the website. That works fine. The form is represented by "RegisterUser" Form. 
The customer, on the other hand, is created in the purchase process. However, it extends the standard django user model. Whereas the registered user is a simple django user.

**Form code:**

```
    class RegisterUser(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30,
                                regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                                            "@/./+/-/_ only."),
                                error_messages={
                                    'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                                                 "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    email = forms.RegexField(label=_("E-Mail"), max_length=100,
                             regex=r'^[\w.@_-]+$',
                             help_text=_("Your E-Mail address"),
                             error_messages={
                                 'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                                              "@/./-/_ characters.")})

    first_name = forms.RegexField(label=_("First Name"), max_length=30,
                                  regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                  help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                                              "@/./+/-/_ only."),
                                  error_messages={
                                      'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                                                   "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})

    last_name = forms.RegexField(label=_("Last Name"), max_length=30,
                                 regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                 help_text=_("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                                             "@/./+/-/_ only."),
                                 error_messages={
                                     'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                                                  "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})

    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text=_("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        return email


    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
        return first_name


    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        return last_name


    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['duplicate_username'],
            code='duplicate_username',
        )

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegisterUser, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class SaveCustomer(RegisterUser):
    dob = forms.DateTimeField(label=_("Date of Birth"))
    newsletter = forms.BooleanField(label=_("Newsletter?"), initial=True, required=False)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(SaveCustomer, self).save()

        customer = Customer()
        customer.user = user
        customer.dob = self.cleaned_data['dob']
        customer.newsletter = self.clearned_data['newsletter']

        if commit:
            customer.save()

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ("username", 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'dob')
```

I have followed the official documentation about extending the user model and I chose to use a OneToOneField for my customer model. Therefore, I am trying a similar approach for the forms.

Unfortunately it is not that simple. The problem in this code is the save function.

I do not want to write additional code for the customer form that does exactly the same as the RegisterUser form. (I also know there is already a default register user form provided by django). In my logic, it should be simple enough to have the register user form for a normal user registration and a form that extends those fields for customers. At the moment, there is only date of birth (dob) and a newsletter, this is just to get it working with some examples.

However, the save function in the customer form does not call the save function of the RegisterUser Form. But because of the OneToOne Field dependency the user needs to be saved before the customer can be saved.

I have come accross this: [Extending forms in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544579/extending-forms-in-django) but it has not helped me.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.
from usercp.forms import SaveAddress
from usercp.forms import SaveCustomer


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'purchaseorder/step1.html', {})


def step1(request, ptitle):
    if request.POST:
        form = SaveCustomer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            customer = form.save()
            return redirect('/purchase/step2/%s' % ptitle, {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'purchaseorder/step1.html', {})
    else:
        # create the form
        form = SaveCustomer()

    return render(request, 'purchaseorder/step1.html', {'form': form})


def step2(request, ptitle):
    if request.POST:
        form = SaveAddress(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            address = form.save(commit=False)
            # CREATE USEER FIRST!
            address.customer = request.user
            address.save()
            return redirect('/purchase/step3/%s' % ptitle, {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'purchaseorder/step2.html', {})
    return render(request, 'purchaseorder/step2.html', {})
```

**Trace Output:**

```
Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_summernote',
 'usercp',
 'products',
 'clickatell',
 'downloadcenter',
 'contact',
 'purchase',
 'purchaseorder',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'limeshp.middleware.AutoLogout')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/vhosts/limeshp/limeshp/../purchaseorder/views.py" in step1
  16.             user = form.save()
File "/var/www/vhosts/limeshp/limeshp/../usercp/forms.py" in save
  239.     def save(self, commit=True):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
  457.                              construct=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
  103.         instance.save()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  591.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  619.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  700.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  733.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  921.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  920.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py" in execute
  159.         return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py" in _record
  101.             return method(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  81.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  133.                 six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  128.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  174.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /purchase/step1/enterprise
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")
```

There is the other problem, that I run this through WSGI on Apache and sometimes refreshing the page gives different outputs. 
here is another traceback, where the call actually continues but still fails:

**Traceback 2**

```
Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_summernote',
 'usercp',
 'products',
 'clickatell',
 'downloadcenter',
 'contact',
 'purchase',
 'purchaseorder',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'limeshp.middleware.AutoLogout')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/vhosts/limeshp/limeshp/../purchaseorder/views.py" in step1
  16.             customer = form.save()
File "/var/www/vhosts/limeshp/limeshp/../usercp/forms.py" in save
  240.         user = super(SaveCustomer, self).save()
File "/var/www/vhosts/limeshp/limeshp/../usercp/forms.py" in save
  227.         user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])

Exception Type: AttributeError at /purchase/step1/enterprise
Exception Value: 'Customer' object has no attribute 'set_password'
```

That error is correct though. There is no set_password on the Customer. That is all user related not customer related.

**models.py**

```
from billing.utils import required
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import datetime


class CustomerType(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False)
    # Following fields from official user
    #first_name
    #last_name
    #email

    #limeshp Customer Fields
    type = models.OneToOneField(CustomerType)

    startDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now(), editable=False, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  #needs activation email #at the moment its true for development...
    gender = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)  #1=male 0=female

    # Extra Information
    newsletter = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s " % (self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why `SaveCustomer.save()` does not call `RegisterUser.save()` ensure you are creating an instance of SaveCustomer before saving the form on purchaseorder/views.py (line 16) and let me know.

Comment: @avenet thank you. I have updated my question. I added the views. I think I am already doing what you were saying. For the completeness I have also added the model, which has nothing to do with it I believe, but for a better understanding as well as a second traceback.

Comment: The second traceback happens because `Customer`, which is the model of the SaveCustomer form is not a User, so even when you call it via the specialised class, it has not the set_password method.

Comment: @avenet that makes sense. However, shouldn't python/django recognise that it is in the RegisterUser form at that point in time and work with those methods ?

Comment: Python doesn't recognise it, because your Customer class does not implement those methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SaveCustomer.save()` which maps to your `Customer` fails because its user instance is None and it never creates the user even when you call `RegisterUser.save()`, because your model in the form is set to `Customer` when you save a `SaveCustomer` form.

For the same reason, `RegisterUser.save()` fails because its form instance (according to step 2, a `Customer`), doesn't contain a set_password().

As a solution, I don't recommend for this particular problem using form inheritance. In my opinion, form inheritance is really useful when used on forms having the same `model` attribute, but as you see, when it is used on different models, it messes up.

Consider creating a unique user model (I'd recommend you inheriting from AbstractUser), or creating separate implementations of save().

Comment: Thank you the AbstractUser works much better and is easier to do than expected.